# Text preprocessing

Tags: python, corpus

I have one text like this:

[image]

I need to tokenize zhe text: one word per line and at the end of the sentence one empty line.
The problem is, some sentences do not have "." at the end. So I need to put "." and newline for  if there are nu punctuation.

```
input = "europarltokenized.txt"
output = "europarlpreprocessing.txt"
nline = "\n"

with open(input, "r") as file:
    with open(output, "w") as file2:
        for line in file:
            if not line.startswith("<"):
                line=line.split()
                for elem in line:
                    file2.write(elem + "\n")
                    if elem == "." or elem=="!" or elem =="?":
                        file2.write("\n")
```

Comment: Can you show, what exactly the answer should be, at least for few first lines?

Comment: Zatwierdzenie      /n                                                                                 protokołu \n  z \n poprzedniego \n  posiedzenia \n :\n  patrz \n  protokół \n . \n \n  Skład \n

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it will work for Europarl, but [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) includes sentence segmentation models for Polish:

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/polish.pickle')

text = u'''Unia Europejska, UE – gospodarczo-polityczny związek 28
demokratycznych państw europejskich. Unia powstała 1 listopada 1993 na
mocy podpisanego 7 lutego 1992 traktatu z Maastricht jako efekt
wieloletniego procesu integracji politycznej, gospodarczej i
społecznej. Korzenie współczesnej integracji europejskiej sięgają
okresu powojennego i ograniczały się do 6 państw
zachodnioeuropejskich.'''

ss = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
```

This works fine on text from Wikipedia:

```
>>> ss
[u'Unia Europejska, UE \xe2\x80\x93 gospodarczo-polityczny ...',
 u'Unia powsta\xc5\x82a 1 listopada 1993 na\nmocy podpisanego  ...',
 u'Korzenie wsp\xc3\xb3\xc5\x82czesnej integracji europejskiej ...']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code was already pretty close:

```
input = "europarltokenized.txt"
output = "europarlpreprocessing.txt"

with open(input, "r") as f, open(output, "w") as f2:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith("<CHAPTER ID="):
            sl = line.split()
            for token in sl:
                f2.write(token + "\n")
            if not sl[-1] in [".", "?", "!"]:
                f2.write(".\n")
            f2.write("\n")
```